# 1995 Toyota Corolla cranks but wont start

Tags: toyota, corolla

I am having problems with a toyota corolla '95. When i turn the ignition it cranks and doesn't die out but it wont start. I tried jumping the car but it still will not start. 
I have tried applying the gas pedal.

What are the possible causes for this and how can i further diagnose the car?

Comment: Does it act like it *wants* to start, but doesn't quite get there?

Comment: Could be a bad fuel pump. However you should also check you are getting proper spark as well.

Comment: And which engine does your car have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two big categories for cranks but failure to start  are

1) no fuel

2) no spark

Things to check for no fuel: a) out of gas, b)bad fuel pump, c) clogged fuel filter

Things to check for no spark: a) see if you have any spark...lots of websites and videos about this  b) bad pickup sensor in ignition system  c) bad timing

Without personally looking at your car, I can't give you more specific advice.

Comment: actually I have figured it out. It was distributors cap. Thanks for your help

Comment: As a side note, an extremely common issue with that generation is the IAC valve or throttle body itself.